# Webpack: Using Component specific css render different in html?

Tags: html, css, node.js, webpack, webpack-style-loader

By following this tutorial,

https://github.com/christianalfoni/react-webpack-cookbook/wiki/Loading-CSS#component-specific

i tried implementing this logic, this is how it is implemented.

[image: Setup]

[image: webpack-config]

This is how it is rendered on the web,
[image: HTML Render]

As you can see the problem, css is not applied for the navbar class, because classname is rendered as **".app-components-navbar-navbar-navbar-wrapper".** but the classname should be **"navbar-wrapper"**

1. How to resolve this?
2. Is this how it supposed to work?
3. How can i achieve component specific css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your loader for the *css*, try changing the value for ***localIdentName*** from `[path][name]-[local]` to `[local]`. The ident name basically means that it will create *css* class name in the following format. **"`.app-components-navbar-navbar-navbar-wrapper`"** means **`app/component/navbar`** is place where it is defined and navbar is name of file. Local signifies your name of class in *css*.

Hope it helps